# Docker Installation - Issue with Enabling Virtualization

Tags: docker, installation, virtualization

I'm trying to install Docker for windows 10 enterprise edition. as part of installation I enabled virtualization in Bios but after enabling it my monitor screen is turning black. If I disable hyperV my screen is not turning black but Docker is not starting. Please help me. TIA.

Comment: have you installed the hyper-v on "Turn Windows features on or off" ? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization

Comment: HyperV is installed and enabled on my PC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you can give it a try:

Download and Install Docker `v17.09`.

[link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#stable-releases-of-2017)